# MacOS : access SSH from UI

Tags: macos, ssh

Greetings,

Is there an easy way to access SSH server without installing a client.
Like in linux (Gnome) I can type ssh://192.168.2.38 and access the resource.

thanks

Comment: I'd imagine that this would be a superuser question, but you can open a terminal (Applications->Utilities->Terminal) and use ssh on the command line (ssh 192.168.2.38 would be the command)

Comment: He wants graphical support, like Nautilus. But of course this is superuser material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [macfusion](http://www.macfusionapp.org/).  This will mount a filesystem via SSH in your finder.

Answer (score 7):

Just fire up Terminal.app and enter the following command:

```
ssh username@192.168.2.38
```

Of course, replacing `username` with your actual username.

You will then be prompted for your password.

Comment: in case you don't know how to use Spotlight, its in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

Comment: +1 for doing it old school! 'cause the Terminal.app is a GUI :P

Answer (score 2):

You already have a (commandline) client installed. You can open the Terminal and use it.

AFAIK, there is no graphical tool which supports SSH on MacOS out of the box like Nautilus does on Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

what if you type "cmd-k" to brig up the "Open a Connection" window in the Finder?